# Why the sudden rise in usage of "吓死宝宝了"?

Tags: expressions

> 吓死宝宝了

All of a sudden this "phrase" (if we can even call it that) is everywhere. I'm reading it, hearing it and seeing it everywhere.

What gives to the sudden rise in usage of this expression?

Comment: No more than an Internet meme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because of the Internet, which made this sentence popular. There was once a boy in Sina Weibo (China's version of Twitter) who sent a threat to a girl. The girl on Sina Weibo replied to express her dissatisfaction. The message was "吓死宝宝了".

It soon got around on Weibo. Many people were talking about this. So now many people use this sentence to express their discontent by force or threat.

Comment: As all memes go, often used ironically.

Answer (score 0):

1. It came from this variety show in China, ZheJiang called Hurry up, Brother <<奔跑吧兄弟>>. One of the actors mentioned this phrase.
2. Chinese-translated Teletubbies 《天线宝宝》- Po said this phrase in chinese as "宝宝" means teletubbies.

There are more examples like "吓死爹了" and netizens changed the wordings to make it sound more adorable.

Answer (score -1):

As @sis say, this sentence comes from Weibo (Chinese use it instead of Twitter).

吓死宝宝了means

> Oh My God

Yeah , maybe you can understand .

Comment: 吓死 means "scare (almost) to death", and 宝宝 means "baby". So 吓死宝宝了 literally translates as "(it almost) scared baby to death". Doesn't make sense, right? Well, in this sentence, 宝宝 could refer to the speaker themselves. Sometimes people use third person in place of first person pronouns - it's called "illeism". (Check out http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/illeismterm.htm). So, 吓死宝宝了 properly translates as "it almost scared me to death"!

Comment: @PotatoChip yeah, you are right. Sorry , my English is very poor , so maybe I can not translate the sentences very well. Hah, I'm a Chinese, want to improve my English.

Comment: It's ok, I'm Chinese too, I understand.